# Are these two equivalent

Tags: calculus

When finding derivatives, a useful tool is $(a^x)' = (a^x)ln(a)$.
Now say I have $2^{3x}$. When trying to find the derivative, are these two equivalent?
$(2^x)ln(2)(3)$ and $(3x)2^{3x - 1}$

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent, the first derivative is given by $$(2^{3x})'=2^{3x}\ln(2)\cdot 3$$ by the chain rule.

Comment: Why doesn't the power rule apply here as well?

Comment: Since $$(a^x)'=a^x\ln(a)$$ and your case is $$a=2$$

Answer (score 1):

Both $(2^x)ln(2)(3)$ and $(3x)2^{3x - 1}$ are wrong !

We have $2^{3x}=8^x$, hence $(2^{3x})'=8^x \ln (8).$

Comment: So was the rule taught to me incorrect? $(
a
x
)
′
=(
a
x
)ln(a)$